# Is there a `Real` equivalent to `FromDigits`?

Tags: number-representation

One can extract an `Integer`'s digits using `IntegerDigits` and reassemble them into the `Integer` using `FromDigits`. Is there a function that reassembles the output of `RealDigits` into the `Real`?

Comment: `N@FromDigits[RealDigits[123.55555]]`?

Comment: @kguler: didn't realize fromdigits accounted for offset.. right in the details in the doc... +1

Comment: @kguler Post an answer? It seems it's worth spelling out because people are not always aware that FromDigit already does this.

Comment: @Szabolcs & rasher thank you both. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [FromDigits>>Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromDigits.html):

> [image: Blockquote]

For example:

```
N@FromDigits[RealDigits[123.55555]]
(* 123.556 *)
```